# How would i make more entities spawn over time thus making it more difficult

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i mean i think it says it in the title but basically i want to know hot to make it so that  isTimeToSpawn would be activated more often the longer my game continues or something else that does the same thing.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Spawner : MonoBehaviour {

public GameObject[] attackerPrefabArray;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    foreach (GameObject thisAttacker in attackerPrefabArray) {
        if (isTimeToSpawn (thisAttacker)) {
            Spawn (thisAttacker);
        }
    }   
}

void Spawn (GameObject myGameObject) {
    GameObject myAttacker = Instantiate (myGameObject) as GameObject;
    myAttacker.transform.parent = transform;
    myAttacker.transform.position = transform.position;
}

bool isTimeToSpawn (GameObject attackerGameObject) {
    Attacker attacker = attackerGameObject.GetComponent<Attacker>();

    float meanSpawnDelay = attacker.seenEverySeconds;
    float spawnsPerSecond = 1 / meanSpawnDelay;

    if (Time.deltaTime > meanSpawnDelay) {
        Debug.LogWarning ("Spwan rate capped by frame rate");
    }

    float threshold = spawnsPerSecond * Time.deltaTime / 5;

    return (Random.value < threshold);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the variables from UnityEngine.Time. one which makes more sense to you. then you have to mix it with your Random.

for example

```
Random.Range(timeSinceLevelLoad, MaxValue);
```